# Case Assignment Rules running Multiple Times - Negative Impact

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice, performance, assignment-rules

I have a bit of an odd question. Is there a negative impact running assignment rules on a Case object on every insert/update? We have a use case where we need to run when the user uses inline edit, but only with certain criteria, but I'm wondering if that's necessary to use a trigger to only run the rules when it meets criteria or just run the rules every time. It would be difficult to maintain over time in a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some "wall clock" time involved, but running assignment rules does not materially affect any of the governor limits (e.g. SOQL queries, CPU time, etc), and likely won't cause any significant impact. This suggestion doesn't immediately raise any red flags, except I'd possibly be concerned that the case might be "accidentally" transferred when it shouldn't have been (but this is more dependent on sharing rules, etc).

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the Salesforce docs, they specifically say anything about performance as well and they do have an option to set the assignment checkbox to checked by default at the layout level.